# Node Express Mocha test: TypeError: chai.request is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mocha.js, chai

I have a Typscript app and API. I wrote the below test per numerous Google searches and some examples found here on SO and other places. I see no issue in the test code. Googling `TypeError: chai.request is not a function`, so far is getting me now where. Do you see my error below?

Thank you, thank you, thank you for any help :-)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I solved this by the following approach (Express.js with TypeScript)

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

Hope it helps.

*Remember to install* **@types/chai** *and other type definition packages for the block above to work*

Comment: I was missing that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I can reproduce the problem if I enable the `esModuleInterop` compiler option.  When this option is enabled, `import * as chai from 'chai';` only imports the members that the `chai` module has at the time it is imported.  Indeed, I believe it's considered dodgy to add exports to an ES module at runtime.  Try `import chai from 'chai';` or `import chai = require('chai');` instead; either one is working for me.

Comment: You are a savior!

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing `import` and `require` syntax, it's a bad idea!

Use only `import` syntax :

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as chai-http from 'chai-http';

chai.use(chai-http);
```

**Edit**

Unfortunately, it seems that the es6 module syntax is not supported in chai-http. You can see the issue [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19480)

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chai-http);
```

Comment: Yes I discovered the module import issue. I found multiple different ways of loading and linking chai/chai-http. The part that's killing me is no one is report my error. At least I cannot find it. So this issue is very obscure and I cannot resolve it. Thank you for the reply :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for the replies! Ultimately I had to change where/how `chai.request` was being imported and rewrite the test a good bit. Based on the code in the test you might think 1 or more of the first 5 lines are not necessary, but they *all* are. Assuming the rest api is started up on 3000, the following code works and the test passes.

Am I writing this api request test correctly? I'm just now learning Mocha/Chai so it's probably wrong...

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
import { Response } from 'superagent';
import { request, expect } from 'chai';

describe('AppController', () => {
    describe('Route GET /app', () => {
        it('Should GET to /app', async () => {
            const res: Response = await request('http://0.0.0.0:3000').get('/app');
            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            expect(res).to.be.a('object');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: looks good to me.  Perhaps, we can improve the code by checking the actual response value instead of just `object`

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
const chai =require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

Then use

```
describe('Chat', () => {
it('should return all data',async()=>{
            chai.request("https://google.com")
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
             expect(res).to.have.status(200);
             done();
             });
        })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue on my own machine. This is how I solve it.

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

I also need to install **@types/chai-http** so the compiler knows.

```
npm install @types/chai-http --save-dev
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I get error - TypeError: chai.request is not a function

Answer (score 0):

install from github

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai-http": "git+https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http.git",
  },
```